# Google+ Know if a user like my fanpage

Tags: google-plus, social-networking, google-plus-one, socialauth

I actually use the Google "HTML" API for my webbapp. The user is already login with Google API and I want to know if he like my G+ page for show more information. I did not find how I could do that. It is possible ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Google+ API to tell if a specific user has +1'd a specific URL or page.